# Bind the textbox value with values in other controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `textbox` whose text value I want to bind based on the values selected in two other controls.

For example, I have a `ListBox` and I choose a value say "Blue" and one other `TextBox` whose text value is say a Name - "Sam".
So I want my `TextBox.Text` value to be like "Blue_Sam".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MultiBinding`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>    
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
            <Binding ElementName="yourComboBox" Path="SelectedText" />
            <Binding ElementName="yourTextBox" Path="Text" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Also if I change the values in the "yourTextBox" or my listpicker, the TextBox text values would update automatically?.
And yes, how to show the Path value for a listpicker.

Comment: It should. Try it, I haven't tested the code. What is the ListPicker? Is it a control or what? Haven't heard about it

Comment: Yah its a windows phone control, similar to a drop down box.

Comment: Anyways I am also yet to try your code. I wil definately test on my machine too and get back.

Comment: Take a look on it's properties. It should have a property such as `SelectedText` or `Text` or `SelectedItem`. Do you fill it by string values?

Comment: I have defined TextBlock Text under list picker. So when clicked on the listpicker it would show the TextBlock Texts. Also if the control is say a ListBox, then what would be my path.
The ListBox has string values.

Comment: A value of `Path` is a name of a property, which contains a value you want to show. For a `ListBox` which is filled by `string` values it will be `SelectedValue` property

Answer (score 1):

well, if u dont want a complicated solution then u should try this--->

```
private void listPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
        var text = urTextBox.Text;        
        urTextBox.Text = lpi.Content + "_" + text; 
    }

    private void OtherTextBoxChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Othertext = (sender as TextBox).Text
        var text = urTextBox.Text;        
        urTextBox.Text = text + "_" + Othertext; 
    }
```